# Python: insert scientific notation in selected subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, scientific-notation

I have a 2-subplot image like this, which features scientific notation only in the case of `Series 2`:

I want scientific notation to be featured for `Series 1` as well, so that I can use the same y scale.

This is how I create the image:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(16, 8))
from matplotlib.ticker import OldScalarFormatter, ScalarFormatter

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(x, y1, color='k')
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('y1',fontsize=12)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12)
plt.title('Series 1',fontsize=14)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(x, y2, color='k')
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('y2',fontsize=12)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12)
plt.title('Series 2',fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

I have tried with `ScalarFormatter`:

```
plt.subplot(121)
yfmt = ScalarFormatter()
yfmt.set_powerlimits((0,8))
plt.plot(x, y1, color='k')
ax[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('y1',fontsize=12)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12)
plt.title('Series 1',fontsize=14)
```

but it does not work. I have also tried with `get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(True)`:

```
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(x, y1, color='k')
ax[0].get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(True)
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('y1',fontsize=12)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12)
plt.title('Series 1',fontsize=14)
```

but it does not work either. How would you make the scientific notation appear in the first subplot just as it appears in the second one?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. No matter what data I try, both subplots behave the same. See [mcve].

Comment: I know about the minimal example, but I cannot make the original data available, unfortunately.

Comment: You are of course not supposed to use your original data (nobody wants to download some datafile from the internet anyways), but some data that allows to reproduce the issue. As said, just using some random data, I cannot reproduce the issue.